# Capture Screenshot of Element with Fixed Element Positioning

Tags: java, jquery, html, css, selenium

I have no issue extracting a sub image from a web page via `Selenium`. I first retrieve a screenshot of the entire page and then I extract sub image using the element coordinates.

```
Dimension elementDimension = webElement.getSize();
Point elementPoint = webElement.getLocation();

BufferedImage bufferedImageScreenshot = takeScreenshotByAShotRtrnBufferedImage(driver);



BufferedImage bufferedSubImage = bufferedImageScreenshot.getSubimage(elementPoint.x, elementPoint.y,
                elementDimension.width, elementDimension.height);
```

This works perfectly every time - except I noticed that some websites have certain elements that scroll along with you as you view (or scroll down) the web page. When this happens, the element that I want is covered by the element that moves along with you as you scroll.

For example, if you go to [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00V7T1YRQ](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00V7T1YRQ) and  try extracting the sub element:  `.//*[@id='aplus']`  from  the web page, the result is:

http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img922/7974/VYFPUU.png

Instead of the expected result of:

http://imageshack.com/a/img922/9517/AB8O2Q.png

How can I get the intended image without being blurred by the element in red?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just delete that floating element. It has an id = miniATF_feature_div. If you execute the javascript below, it should remove it from the page until you reload.

```
document.getElementById('miniATF_feature_div').remove()
```

If you don't know how to do that, there are plenty of tutorials and questions here on SO with some sample code.

Side note:
There's no reason to use XPath when you are just looking up an ID, e.g. `.//*[@id='aplus']`. Just use `By.id("aplus")`... it's easier to read, understand, better supported, and faster.

Comment: I up voted you. I don't understand why someone down voted it. It is the correct answer. Thanks!